# Can't make CSS submenu show up below its parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I've a module which renders `html` menu markup. This markup can't be overridden.
So in order to make the menu look like it should I have to write some custom CSS code.

The problem is that on hover the submenu doesn't show up underneath its parent.

**html:**

```
<div class="moduletable_menu slider-menu">
   <ul class="menu">
      <li class="item-122 default current active"><a href="/skarda/en/">Products From Metal</a></li>
      <li class="item-126 menu-deeper menu-parent">
         <a href="#">Products<span class="menu-toggler"></span></a>
         <ul class="menu-child">
            <li class="item-123"><a href="/skarda/en/products/sliding-fence">Sliding Fence</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider-menu {
  display: block;  
}

.slider-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  color:#fff;
}

.slider-menu  .menu-deeper.menu-parent{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider-menu  .menu-deeper.menu-parent li a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider-menu > ul li.menu-deeper > a::after {

    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f107";
    float: right;
    margin-left: 7px;

}

.slider-menu .menu-child {
  display: none;           
}

.slider-menu .menu-child li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
}

.slider-menu .menu-child li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.slider-menu .menu-deeper.menu-parent:hover > .menu-child {
  animation: spFadeInUp 400ms ease-in;
  display: block;

}


.slider-menu ul li a:hover {  
  color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhakeyg4/)

So, I've missed something... Need proper corrections.

Comment: You have all `ul` `float: right` with this selector: `.slider-menu ul`. When creating nested menus like this you might want to utilize the `>` more often... `.slider-menu > ul`

Comment: working example highly appreciated

Comment: Like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfxemwo1/), but also importantly added `position: absolute; top: 100%;` to the `.menu-child`

Comment: if you'd post it as an answer - I'd accept it

Comment: Looks like `.menu-child { position: absolute }` is the key here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `position: absolute; top: 100%;` to the child menu will position the menu absolutely directly below the parent `li` with `position: relative;`

```
.slider-menu .menu-child {
  display: none;       
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.slider-menu {
  display: block;  
  position:absolute;/*just to position  it to the left corner in the JSFiddle example*/
  top:0;
}

.slider-menu > ul {
  float: right;
}

.slider-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  color:#fff;
}

.slider-menu  .menu-deeper.menu-parent{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider-menu  .menu-deeper.menu-parent li a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider-menu > ul li.menu-deeper > a::after {

    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f107";
    float: right;
    margin-left: 7px;

}

.slider-menu .menu-child {
  display: none;           
}

.slider-menu .menu-child li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
}

.slider-menu .menu-child li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.slider-menu .menu-deeper.menu-parent:hover > .menu-child {
  animation: spFadeInUp 400ms ease-in;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}


.slider-menu ul li a:hover {  
  color: red;
}


@keyframes spFadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="moduletable_menu slider-menu">
   <ul class="menu">
      <li class="item-122 default current active"><a href="/skarda/en/">Products From Metal</a></li>
      <li class="item-126 menu-deeper menu-parent">
         <a href="#">Products<span class="menu-toggler"></span></a>
         <ul class="menu-child">
            <li class="item-123"><a href="/skarda/en/products/sliding-fence">Sliding Fence</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Update

To match the parent text horizontally you can match the padding of 15px that the parent `<li>` has

```
.slider-menu .menu-child {
  display: none;       
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%
 padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: And the last question: how the child could be aligned with a parent, horizontally? Like: `.slider-menu .menu-child > li {
  width: 150px;  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;

}`?

Comment: see update. you can match padding or set `left: 15px;`

Comment: ya or you can put the padding on the child menu's li... either works